# Azure AD B2C Saml Authentication

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0

I have been trying to connect my application for the last week and a half with no success. I have gotten normal Azure Ad to work along with both OneLogin and Okta. I'm currently working with the OneLogin Saml example project because it would be easy to incorporate into my own once its working. A few questions on the issue to see where I'm going wrong

What are the Entity Id, Single Sign On, and Single Logout urls? Not the definitions but how do I find/make them?

What are the proper configurations for identifieruri, samlmetadataurl, and reddirect uri for the azure app?

What is the importance of the issuer uri in the custom policies? It doesn't seem to affect behavior only the entityID in the policy's metadata

I am currently getting this error.
"Application registered corresponding to IssuerUri "http://localhost:8000/metadata/" in AuthRequest does not have assertion consumer service URL "http://localhost:8000/" specified in its metadata"

I previously got the same error with the test Saml app found here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers

https://samltestapp2.azurewebsites.net/SP

This was fixed in the demo app by adding an identifieruri in the form https://domainname.onmicrosoft.com/appname
What else could cause this error? Nothing I change seems to modify the error message

Comment: If you are trying https://samltestapp2.azurewebsites.net/SP make sure to use 
**AssertionConsumerServiceURL**="https://samltestapp2.azurewebsites.net/SP/AssertionConsumer"  in the custom policy.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to use the onelogin example app https://pythonhosted.org/python-saml/#

Comment: I actually have the samltestapp2.azurewebsites.net/SP working. And I could use literally any url for the issuer uri and it still works. Is there an assertion consumer service in the custom policy?

Comment: Hi @user14024185 are you still looking for any help?

Comment: Yes. I think the main issue is that I can't set the Assertion consumer service in the custom policy.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. The ACS URL in the SAML AuthN request is not present as a ACS URL in the metadata document

Comment: @user14024185 have you managed to resolve this? facing the same issue after following the ms docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#overview